# Native Crash in getting bitmap from resource

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, drawable, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a native crash:

```
A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x55766f1b00 passed to try_realloc_chunk
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 32219 (onPool-worker-1)
```

when executing the `drawable.draw(canvas)` line in the following method:

```
fun getBitmapFromResource(context: Context, imageRes: Int, iconSize: Float = CATEGORY_ICON_SIZE): Bitmap? {
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageRes)
    if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
        return drawable.bitmap
    }
    val size = GraphicsUtils.toPx(context, iconSize)
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    drawable!!.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    drawable.draw(canvas)  // crash!!
    return bitmap
}
```

The drawable is `VectorDrawable` implementation. I am executing this code on a background thread in a coroutine. 
I added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to `build.gradle` file, but it did not help. 
I need bitmap object because from its width and height I draw a custom chart and I need to perform size calculations there.
I had the suspicion that multi-threading might break the process, so I added this code in the `runBlocking` section (still on a background thread) - no effect.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of investigation, I fixed the issue.
The problem seems to be that more than one coroutine was entering the method at the same time. I used `Mutex` to make sure only one coroutine can be inside the method.

```
object UIUtilsSingleton {
     private val mutex = Mutex()

     suspend fun getBitmapFromResource(context: Context, imageRes: Int): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        mutex.withLock {
            val iconSize = 42f
            val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageRes)

            if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
                return drawable.bitmap
            }

            val size = GraphicsUtils.toPx(context, iconSize)
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            drawable!!.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            drawable.draw(canvas)

        }
    return bitmap
    }
   }
```